# Getting parameters from Object

Tags: java, arrays, getter

I really need your help. Don`t be scared of a title, cause I don`t really know how to describe a problem. So I have an array

```
public static final Server[] SERVERS = {
        new Server(0, "Test0", "localhost", "00000", "client"),
        new Server(1, "Test1", "localhost", "00001", "client"),
        new Server(2, "Test2", "localhost", "00002", "client")
};
```

How can I get Test0, Test1 and Test2 from that array? I thought about SERVERS[2], but that will select whole object. I have no clue how to get that..
I will really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance :3

P.S.For example:

`File f = new File("abc");`

How can I call that thing, which is in brackets? I mean whats a proper name of "abc"? Parameter? Variable?

Comment: If you have e.g. a method declaration `void m(int x) {...}`, then `x` is a *parameter*. If you then call the method `m(10)`, then `10` is an *argument*. The same applies to constructors, so `"abc"` is an argument to the [`File` constructor's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-) parameter `pathname`.

Comment: In `File f = new File("abc");` , `"abc"` is an argument.  We use the parameter term for the declaration in the method : `public File(String pathname) ...` . Here : `pathname` is a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Remember Servers is an array of servers, so you can do SERVERS[x] and that will give you access to the server object located at the given index x.

After that you just need to use the getters, something like:

```
String name = SERVERS[2].getName();
int index = SERVERS[2].getIndex();
//etc etc
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a method that returns the server name in the `Server` class.

For example :

```
public String getName(){
  return name;
}
```

In this way you could do it to retrieve it :

```
String name = SERVERS[2].getName();
```